# Aws S3 CLI entire folder download to local

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

Is there a aws cli command that allows to download an entire folder from s3  to local machine, instead of creating a folder locally.

For example , when i run the following command

```
aws cp s3 s3://<MY-BUCKET>/folder1 . --recursive
```

I expect the "folder1" to downloaded to my local machine along with its contents.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12):

If you want it to copy `folder1/`, you could use:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<MY-BUCKET>/ . --recursive --exclude '*' --include 'folder1/*'
```

This tells it to copy the root directory, but only include `folder1/*`.

See: [AWS CLI - Use of Exclude and Include Filters](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `sync` method of the s3 cli

```sh
aws s3 sync s3://<MY-BUCKET>/folder1 .
```

if you really need the folder, you could do something like

```sh
mkdir ./folder1
aws s3 sync s3://<MY-BUCKET>/folder1 ./folder1
```

Comment: Hello @allan thanks for the response, but still when i run the command its the files inside the folder that are downloaded. 

abraham.johnson[15:13:55]aws s3 sync s3://<PAth>/mqwt6 .

abraham.johnson[16:25:48]ls
hared.tgz
system.tgz